# How can I get GeoJSON from Esri software to load in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, arcgis-pro

So I am trying to take a GeoJSON file that I have generated from an Esri shapefile in ArcGIS Pro, but it is not rendering on the map for some reason...

The GeoJSON that was created from ArcGIS Pro is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waderoberts123/tethysapp-yaque_del_norte_viewer/master/tethysapp/yaque_del_norte_viewer/public/GeoJSON/yaque_del_norte.geojson). I have included my current JavaScript below as well. I feel like there might be something wrong with the way the data is formatted or something, I don't really know, as I am unfamiliar with all of this. I left in some commented code that didn't seem to do anything differently, but maybe it can work if a small change is made.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let map = L.map("map").setView([19.042805, -70.581183], 7.2);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/static/yaque_del_norte_viewer/GeoJSON/yaque_del_norte.geojson",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            let myStyle = {
                "color": "#2427ff",
                "weight": 5,
                "opacity": 0.65
            };

            L.geoJSON(data, {style: myStyle}).addTo(map);

            // let yaqueDelNorteLayer = new L.GeoJSON();
            //
            // $(data.features).each(function (key, data) {
            //
            //     console.log(data);
            //     yaqueDelNorteLayer.addData(data);
            // });

            // console.log(yaqueDelNorteLayer);
            //

            // yaqueDelNorteLayer.setStyle(myStyle);
            //
            // yaqueDelNorteLayer.addTo(map);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That GeoJSON says that it is defined in EPSG:4236 but the coordinates are clearly from a projected coordinate system. How did you save it? The coordinates should appear as latitude and longitude values.

Comment: @wfgeo I'm not 100% sure how I saved it, I thought I input the parameter to output to WGS 1984, and that is probably the issue, huh?

Comment: A coordinate string like `[[237865.08519999962,1954470.2309000008],[240225.97360000014,1956308.3763999995]]` is clearly indicative of a projected coordinate system because the numbers are so large. A geographic CRS like WGS84 should have numbers within -180 to 180 and -360 to 360. Try saving it again but be very careful to go through every option to make sure everything is set to EPSG:4326.

Answer (score 1):

I checked a bit what projected CRS might be used in geojson file. Since Yaque del Norte is a river in Dominican Republic, I asumed that CRS is `EPSG:32619` which covers Dominican Republic.

Using `Proj4Leaflet` plugin I unprojected coordinates in geojson object. Resultant features (rivers) exctly cover Dominican Republic.

Code can be something like:

```
var epsg32619 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:32619',
  '+proj=utm +zone=19 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs',                        
  {
   origin: [166021.44, 9329005.18],
   resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5],
  }
);

L.geoJSON(data, {
  style: myStyle,
  coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
    return epsg32619.unproject(L.point(coords));
  }
).addTo(map);
```